# Can condensed milk be safely used after it's 'best before' date?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, milk

It's just that I have an unopened tin of condensed milk which is a couple of months past it's best before date. And I don't feel like throwing it away :(

Comment: Most things in cans will last for many years, as long as the can was intact and not bulging it will be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as it hasn't been opened. 'Best Before' dates refer to quality, not safety, and reflect the date at which the manufacturers believe that it is not up to normal quality standards. Have a taste, and if you think it's OK, go ahead.